# Empty space in post content

Tags: wordpress

http://www.damianc.pl/wp-content/themes/damianc/cphp.png

I've blog based on WordPress, I use plug-in SyntaxHighlighter Evolved. In my posts first codes has empty space in Chrome, but in IE hasn't [image]. How fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the issue is fixable.

I have run into FireFox/Chrome/IE formatting issues working as a Software Developer, and the issue was in the underlining HTML structure. Each browser would interpret the HTML code differently.

You might be able to fix the issue if you can change the HTML that is sent to your posts. If not, I would recommend getting a different code formater. WordPress has a built in format for code triggered by,

```
<code> your code here </code>
```

or

```
<tt> your code here </tt>
```

See link for more detail: [Writing Code in Your Posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_Code_in_Your_Posts)